# Bootstrap navbar-collapse not working on small ans xs devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Can anyone look at this and tell me what am I doing wrong? Other bootstrap - java script elements are working on this webpage. 
Navbar icon is visible, and seems that it' working, but it dont display menu.

This is my code:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"  aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 3,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
    ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You should include some code, rather than linking us to an off site location, external websites change all the time, if someone has the exact same problem they might not get an answer here, so this question is very low value. you should also tell us what errors you get or how things are not working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML on your website contains two  tags with id "bs-example-navbar-collapse-1". This is the HTML I am seeing on the website:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
      </ul>
    </div>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Notice the two  and  tags. Removing the duplicates will sonve your issue.

Comment: This solved my problem. I forgot to remove default bootstrap div #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 and ul #navbar-nav, when, at the same time, I was giving the same code via wp_nac_menu array.